# How can we discover what programming language was used to make a software?

Tags: file-format, development

How can we discover what programming language a software was written in? For example: Office, Photoshop or any other application and their corresponding languages (C#, Java or ...). Does anyone know?

Comment: What about programs with parts written in different languages?

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

[PEiD](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Packers-Crypters-Protectors/PEiD-updated.shtml) offers some info related to the tools used in the development of Windows programs, but is useful only for programmers and other knowledgeable people:

> PEiD is an intuitive application that relies on its user-friendly interface to detect packers, cryptors and compilers found in PE executable files – its detection rate is higher than that of other similar tools since the app packs more than 600 different signatures in PE files.

You may look up general info about famous programs like Office individualy by yourself with the help of a search engine or Wikipedia. For example, see the [Wikipedia page for Photoshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoshop). Its info table tells us that it has been written in **C++**.